# PHP Snipped not rendering in iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to open the user_url within an iframe on a private user page in Wordpress.

I put the following code into a snippet:

```
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('user_url',$userID); ?>
```

When I use the short code on the user page it does display the user URL, I can also use it in an hyperlink like this:

```
<a href="[cmruncode name='dash']">link text</a>
```

But when I put the short code into an Iframe the short code does not change into the URL anymore.

```
<iframe src="[cmruncode name='dash']" height="300" width="300" title="Iframe"></iframe>
```

Does anyone knows why this is not working and know a solution?

Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress shortcode then you have to call shotcode using function `do_shortcode`.

You can try this one

```
<iframe src="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[cmruncode name="dash"]' ); ?>" height="300" width="300" title="Iframe"></iframe>
```

And I'm not sure why anchort text display right output. That's weird.

Anyway if you used `do_shortcode` to output your shortcode then it will work every place.

Answer (score 0):

This only works when I put it directly into the template, in that case no snippet-shortcode is needed at all. But the content needs to be hidden when the user is logged-out.

Normally the plugin "client portal" that I use should take care of this
but it has a content block that does not support PHP and also does not render the php snippet that I made.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put the iframe code completely into a snippet.
Like this:

```html
<iframe src="<?php echo the_author_meta('user_url',$userID); ?>" height="2400" width="100%" title="Iframe"></iframe>
```